# R devtools not able to use CURL

Tags: r, curl, devtools

I am having an issue with the CURL package in R.

I am trying to run the following command: `devtools::install_local("Downloads/rkdb-master")` where rkdb-master is an unzipped Git package. This calls the following:

```
curl -O -J -L https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/raw/master/c/c/k.h
```

However, after the CURL command is ran, I get the following error:

```
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
```

Can someone help me with this issue please?

I looked it up online and the suggestion was: `curl -k -O -J -L https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/raw/master/c/c/k.h`

This works to install the k.h file locally. However, when I run the installation, I cannot force R to use `curl -k -O -J -L https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/raw/master/c/c/k.h` instead of `curl -O -J -L https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/raw/master/c/c/k.h`.

```
> devtools::install_local("C:/Users/mathi/Downloads/rkdb-master")
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
✔  checking for file 'C:\Users\mathi\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp8uglEV\file321424d56a31\rkdb-master/DESCRIPTION' (1s)
─  preparing 'rkdb':
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
   Removed empty directory 'rkdb/c/c'
   Removed empty directory 'rkdb/c'
─  building 'rkdb_0.13.0.tar.gz'
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/mathi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'rkdb' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
curl -O -J -L https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/raw/master/c/c/k.h
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
make: *** [Makevars:52: k.h] Error 35
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'rkdb'
* removing 'C:/Users/mathi/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/rkdb'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/mathi/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp8uglEV/file321456f43831/rkdb_0.13.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I suspect this is specific to `kdb` and their repo. I suggest you contact them / peruse their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me just as fine as the (simpler, updated)

```
remotes::install_github("kxsystems/rkdb")
```

once I ensure I also install `curl` (the binary client) -- and of course also after the other dependencies are installed.

The use of `curl` is a bit of a wart on the part of KxSystems: R now builds with `libcurl` and they could just rely on R's own `download.file()`.  Anyway...  But there is no certicate failure here.

My build (in a container, but on Linux) showed

```
* installing *source* package ‘rkdb’ ...                                                                 
** using staged installation                                                                             
** libs                                                                                                  
UNAME_S="Linux"                                                                                          
curl -O -J -L https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/raw/master/c/c/k.h
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  4126  100  4126    0     0  10557      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10557
curl -O -J -L https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/raw/master/l64/e.o
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100 85616  100 85616    0     0   210k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  557k
gcc -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG     -D_GNU_SOURCE -fpic  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/r-base-LhKvHL/r-base-4.2.3=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c rkdb.c -o rkdb.o
```

after which it continues with minor compilation warnings.

(Also, with that, your Subject here is wrong: `devtools` does not depend or use `curl`; the installation recipe inside the `rkdb` package does so it really is a KxSystems issue.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies. I tried remotes::install_github("kxsystems/rkdb") and still get the certificate failure. However, I am not sure I have the correct version of CURL. I installed CURL using: install.packages("curl"). Did you install it in the same way?

Comment: As I wrote "`curl` (the binary client)" -- that is `/usr/bin/curl` and _not_ the eponymous CRAN package (and, as I wrote, lazyness on the part of KxSystem as they could emulate use of the external `curl` binary via `download.file()`.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. If I undesrtood correctly, I just uninstalled the CRAN CURL package. CURL is installed on my PC:
`curl --version
curl 7.83.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.83.1 Schannel
Release-Date: 2022-05-13
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HSTS IPv6 Kerberos Largefile NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI UnixSockets`
However, when I run the command `remotes::install_github("kxsystems/rkdb")`, I get the same certificate failure. Do you know why this failure persists in my case?

Comment: It has to be on the $PATH so that eg `system("curl --version")` returns.  And no, I have no idea why GitHub will not serve you.  But I think all this is _specific_ to this repo and a general issue.  I suggest contacting KxSystems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will reach out to them!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by altering the default configuration file of CURL. Thank you Dirk Eddelbuettel for your hint.

What worked for me:

1. From the command line, type: `touch .curlrc` (this will create a default configuration file for your CURL - make sure you do not have one or go to step 3)
2. set %USERPROFILE%=C:/Users/*username* (where I created .curlrc)
3. Open .curlrc and type `insecure`
4. remotes::install_github("kxsystems/rkdb") should work now

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice, that is one (good) to remain with `curl` but alter it behavior as needed.